# How to properly create dedicated loggers for desired Ruby on Rails classes, in a nice, compact and generic way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, design-patterns, activesupport-concern

Everything is in the title but for the sake of it:

The company I work for has a really big Ruby On Rails app. After years of development we realized it lacked of logging. Production incidents were sometimes really hard to track and consequently to resolve.

So there was that issue in our backlog to improve the whole logging system.

I started added custom loggers for classes here and there, when really required but it seemed kind of dumb to copy / paste that piece of logic everywhere.

So i wondered: **How to properly create dedicated loggers for desired Ruby on Rails classes, in a nice, compact and generic way ?**

Comment: I wonder if you haven't outgrown simple log files and should consider services like Retrace, Papertrail (not to be confused with the gem), Loggly (etc) or hosting your own ELK stack. They make it simple to just add  tags to the logs and and work even when your apps are deployed to multiple servers.

Comment: Spreading your logs out in multiple files won't necissarily actually have the indended effect and might actually make debugging harder.

Comment: You definitely make a point here. I need to look into those services.

On the spreading makes it harder point, I half-agree let's say, for some cases yes, for other really specific cases we needed to have logs sorted this way. You definitely can't make a log file for every class of your app, but i have specific part of my app where i want to monitor them apart, for those specific logs not to be drown in the tremendous amount of other ones the app can generate. 

That's also why i thought this solution fits my use case: I can simply make a logger available with a simple include

Comment: Also the fact it's lightweight and free is to be considered I guess

Comment: But that's also when the services you pointed out (after looking a bit more into them)  make it useless to split those logs, or insignificant the fact they're flooded in a tremendous amount of others to say it differently, as there's a third party analyzing them if i get it right. 
It's, as you pointed out in the very beginning, a matter of outgrowing the simple logging system or not. And I feel we're mainly on the edge where i work at so I may look at those services even closer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: [SemanticLogger](https://logger.rocketjob.io/) is a good utility for what @max is talking about because it supports sending logs to [multiple types of destinations](https://logger.rocketjob.io/appenders.html) while also supporting [tagged logging](https://logger.rocketjob.io/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was the use of `ActiveSupport::Concern`.

The code is easily understandable and commented so I think just pasting it here will make the best of explanations:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This concern can be included in any class to add a dedicated logger
# This will have the effect of creating a custom logger for the class
# The logger will be accessible through the `logger` class method and
# will create a log file in the `log` directory with the name of the class
# in snake case

# Example of use:
# class SampleClass
#   include DedicatedLoggerConcern
# end
#
# SampleClass.logger.info('Hello world')
#
# # Will write to log/sample_class.log
# :nocov:
module DedicatedLoggerConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    @logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{name.underscore}.log"))
  end

  class_methods do
    attr_reader :logger
  end
end
```

The code comments say it all. Nothing groundbreaking here but I also think that is a really good example of a proper use of `ActiveSupport::Concern`. I often see it used as a way to split models/controllers that get too big into different logical bricks (which may not be wrong neither) but i feel this kind of generic way to add a possibility to any class is more like it's meant to be used (or am I wrong ?).

Feel free to debate, hope this helps :)